# How to install uwsgi on mac m1 with python 3.9.13 and pyenv 2.3.3

Tags: python, macos, pip, uwsgi, arm64

When trying to install the uwsgi from pypi on a Mac M1 (arm-64). I'm getting an error (see bellow).

I know that they are python location issues with uwsgi.

I tried to create a symlink between the `config-3.9-darwin` as indicated on multiple threads:

```
sudo ln -sf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin  /Users/lhulot/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Full configuration:

- python 3.9.13
- pip 22.2.2
- pyenv 2.3.3
- OS: Monterey, 12.4

Do anyone has an idea ?

```bash
Collecting uwsgi
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [165 lines of output]
      /Users/***/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
      installing to build/bdist.macosx-12.2-arm64/wheel
      running install
      using profile: buildconf/default.ini
      detected include path: ['/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
      Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
      detected CPU cores: 10
      configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
      *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
      [thread 2][clang] core/utils.o
...
      [thread 9][clang] core/subscription.o
      core/utils.c:3676:6: warning: variable 'pos' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
              int pos = 0;
                  ^
      1 warning generated.
      [thread 2][clang] core/stats.o
...
      [thread 8][clang] core/rb_timers.o
      core/mount.c:112:16: warning: variable 'mountflags' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
              unsigned long mountflags = 0;
                            ^
      core/mount.c:150:16: warning: variable 'mountflags' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
              unsigned long mountflags = 0;
                            ^
      2 warnings generated.
      [thread 0][clang] core/transformations.o
...
      [thread 1][clang] plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o
      *** uWSGI linking ***
      clang -o build/bdist.macosx-12.2-arm64/wheel/uWSGI-2.0.20.data/scripts/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -lexpat -lintl -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Users/***/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.a
      ld: library not found for -lintl
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      *** error linking uWSGI ***
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for uwsgi did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [147 lines of output]
      /Users/***/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      using profile: buildconf/default.ini
      detected include path: ['/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
      Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
      detected CPU cores: 10
      configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
      *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
      core/utils.o is up to date
...
      plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o is up to date
      *** uWSGI linking ***
      clang -o /Users/***/repos/substra/.venv/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -lexpat -lintl -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Users/***/.pyenv/versions/3.9.13/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.a
      ld: library not found for -lintl
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      *** error linking uWSGI ***
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> uwsgi
```